# How to change language in mapbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I need to change the language of the mapbox in javascript, I only see the below code in the documentation

```
map.setLayoutProperty('country-label', 'text-field', ['get', 'name_de'])
```

but this line of code will only change the country names but I need everything ( city, town, ...etc)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your mapbox style, there will be different text layers. For `dark-v9`, these are the available text layers.

```
country-label
state-label
settlement-label
settlement-subdivision-label
airport-label
poi-label
water-point-label
water-line-label
natural-point-label
natural-line-label
waterway-label
road-label
```

Using the code snippet that you mentioned in the question on the above layers, you should be able to change the language.

```
map.setLayoutProperty('country-label', 'text-field', ['get', 'name_de'])
```

Or you can use [mapbox-language-plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-language) to change the language of all the possible layers.  Here is the working example of the plugin.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Change a map's language</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.4.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-language/v0.10.1/mapbox-gl-language.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.4.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<style>
    #buttons {
        width: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .button {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 20%;
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        background: #ee8a65;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<ul id="buttons">
    <li id='button-fr' class='button'>French</li>
    <li id='button-ru' class='button'>Russian</li>
    <li id='button-de' class='button'>German</li>
    <li id='button-es' class='button'>Spanish</li>
</ul>
<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibXVyYWxpcHJhamFwYXRpIiwiYSI6ImNrMHA1d3VjYzBna3gzbG50ZjR5b2Zkb20ifQ.guBaIUcqkTdYHX1R6CM6FQ';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
    center: [16.05, 48],
    zoom: 2.9
});
  mapboxgl.setRTLTextPlugin('https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-rtl-text/v0.1.0/mapbox-gl-rtl-text.js');
  var mapboxLanguage = new MapboxLanguage({
  defaultLanguage: 'en'
});
 
map.addControl(mapboxLanguage);
  


document.getElementById('buttons').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var language = event.target.id.substr('button-'.length);
    map.setStyle(mapboxLanguage.setLanguage(map.getStyle(), language));
  
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ref: https://blog.mapbox.com/how-to-localize-your-maps-in-mapbox-gl-js-da4cc6749f47

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I want to get the list of all layers and `map.getStyle().layers` this gives me the right data.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a code I have found helpful for me [from github mapbox here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js-docs/issues/41)

```
map.getStyle().layers.forEach(function(thisLayer){
  if(thisLayer.type == 'symbol'){
    map.setLayoutProperty(thisLayer.id, 'text-field', ['get','name_ja'])
  }
})
```

I have modified it to

```
map.getStyle().layers.forEach(function(thisLayer){
        console.log(thisLayer);
            if(thisLayer.id.indexOf('-label')>0){
                console.log('change '+thisLayer.id);
                map.setLayoutProperty(thisLayer.id, 'text-field', ['get','name_fr'])
            }
        });
```

But otherwise you'll have to change the different labels yourself as mentionned by murli-prajapati

Of course, change 'name_xx' by your own language

such as:

```
map.setLayoutProperty('country-label', 'text-field', ['get','name_fr']);
map.setLayoutProperty('state-label', 'text-field', ['get','name_fr']);
map.setLayoutProperty('settlement-label', 'text-field', ['get','name_fr']);
map.setLayoutProperty('settlement-subdivision-label', 'text-field', ['get','name_fr']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that helped me is a cycle placed in *load* event:

```
map.on('load', function() {
           let labels = [ 'country-label', 'state-label', 
           'settlement-label', 'settlement-subdivision-label', 
           'airport-label', 'poi-label', 'water-point-label', 
           'water-line-label', 'natural-point-label', 
           'natural-line-label', 'waterway-label', 'road-label' ];
            
            labels.forEach(label => {
                    map.setLayoutProperty(label, 'text-field', 'get','name_ru']);
            });
 })
```

Language plugin and other stuff didn't work.

Comment: Hello @Mike, your code works for me partially. I can change the country names. But all other things are still in english, no matter if I change it to german or any other language. Just the country names changes. Do you have an idea why this might be?

Comment: @DatamineR would you mind showing your code?

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the solutions in this thread with streets-v12 I found non of them gave me what I needed.

The plug-in doesn’t work at all, and @Mike & @honey59 solutions semi-work, I still found many components not translated.

What did work best for me was to use Mapbox’s studio to create custom map and change the language there to all the components & layers (guide: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/change-language/).

And on my site I know when user is viewing the page on a specific language, so I just needed to map the languages to their custom maps URLs.

I know it’s not the most “technical” dynamic solution, but I found it to be the most complete one

Answer (score 0):

Belatedly, you could use this plugin to change the display language according to the user locale.

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-language

For example:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
    center: [-77.0259, 38.9010],
    zoom: 9
});

const language = new MapboxLanguage();
map.addControl(language);
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Using Mapbox GL JS in React and the plugin suggested.

Comment: @NicktheCommunityScientist It works in Vanilla JS so it's something to do with your implementation. A wild guess is that you should probably do `map.current.addControl()` instead of `map.addControl()`